# No Facebook Friend's email address are returned by using Graph API

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, xamarin.ios

I am going to retrieve Facebook friends email addresses in one of my applications. I have asked the permission for "user_friends" and "email" apart from other permissions, but when I try to get the email addresses for my friends list, email address is not returning. I could able to get other information but not email address. I tested the same using Graph API tool, it is also giving the same result.

Can anyone suggest what was the issue in getting facebook friend's email addresses?

Comment: the answer below is correct, but why would you even want those? what for? anything you send to those would be 100% spam anyway.

Comment: This was never possible. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of getting friends' email addresses. The `email` permission is used to get the user's email address, and `user_friends` permission is to find friends who also uses the same application.

The reason both your app and the Graph API doesn't return email addresses is because it's not possible (for obvious reasons, like spamming). There is no way around this.

If you want to invite friends to use your application, use one of the other methods like Sharing, Requests or Tagging.